# How to send an email with attachment using Python Flask /flask_mail

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-mail

I recently started my adventure with python and only a couple weeks ago I discovered flask. I'm trying to send an email with output.csv file attached using flask. Output.csv has been saved as a result of submitting a html form from my form.html page.

**myform.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(dict(
    DEBUG = True,
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT = 587,
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True,
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False,
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'myemail@gmail.com',
    MAIL_PASSWORD = '*****',
))

mail = Mail(app)


@app.route('/')
def myForm():
   return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/steptwo',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def steptwo():
   if request.method == 'POST':

        id = request.form['id']
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        website = request.form['website']
        requestPhoneNr = request.form['requestPhoneNr']
        requestTopic = request.form['requestTopic']
        requestDescription = request.form['requestDescription']
        requestOriginator = request.form['requestOriginator']

        fieldnames = ['requestPhoneNr', 'requestTopic', 'requestDescription', 'requestOriginator']


        with open('path/to/my/output.csv','a') as inFile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(inFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            writer.writerow({'requestPhoneNr': requestPhoneNr, 'requestTopic': requestTopic, 'requestDescription': requestDescription, 'requestOriginator': requestOriginator})
        msg = Message('Sample title', sender = 'myemai@gmail.com',       recipients = ['myotheremail@gmail.com'])
        msg.body = request.form['id'] + request.form['name'] + request.form['email'] + request.form['website']
        with app.open_resource("path/to/my/output.csv") as fp:
            msg.attach("path/to/my/output.csv", "text/csv", fp.read())
        mail.send(msg)


        return 'Thanks for your input!'






if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Solved!

Comment: `open('path/to/my/output.csv','a')` will append the new row to the end of the file, rather than overwriting the existing file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @snakecharmerb! this solved one of my issues. I updated the post here as now I'm trying to find out how to send an email with flask including my attachment.

Comment: Move `app = Flask(__name__)` _before_ you start assigning things to `app.config`

Comment: I moved this and tried to have both csv file and mail sent as one function, but now I'm receiving this error: NameError: name 'mail' is not defined (updated my post above)

Comment: Hi @ snakecharmerb! I've solved the above by adding mail = Mail(app).Thanks for your help!  However, still struggling with my output.csv file in a separate thread as adding 'a' as you suggested doesn't work for passing multiple values (still getting only single row value, not multiple at once). I described problem further here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279577/html-form-with-flask-problem-with-passing-table-values-to-csv-file