# Html form with flask - problem with passing table values to CSV file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, forms, flask

I'm new to python and hoping that someone on this forum could help me solving my problem.

In the form.html file I have a table called **myTable** where multiple rows can be added/deleted. What I'm trying to achieve is to capture all the possible values for each row added in this table and save it to output.csv file.

Desired output.csv:

```
requestPhoneNr    requestTopic    requestDescription requestOriginator 
 +615331234       Hello World      This is a test.       John Doe
 +1800324567      Greetings!!!     My test description.   Ana Doe
  ...
```

My problem: If there is more than one row added in myTable (form.html) only values for the first row are saved to output.csv instead of all the values from multiple rows. Could someone help me getting this right? Thanks!

**myform.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import csv


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def myForm():
   return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/steptwo',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def steptwo():
   if request.method == 'POST':

        requestPhoneNr = request.form['requestPhoneNr']
        requestTopic = request.form['requestTopic']
        requestDescription = request.form['requestDescription']
        requestOriginator = request.form['requestOriginator']

        fieldnames = ['requestPhoneNr', 'requestTopic', 'requestDescription', 'requestOriginator']


        with open('output.csv','w') as inFile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(inFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            # writerow() will write a row in your csv file
            writer.writerow({'requestPhoneNr': requestPhoneNr, 'requestTopic': requestTopic, 'requestDescription': requestDescription, 'requestOriginator': requestOriginator})

        return 'Thanks for your input!'



if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

**form.html:**

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>

      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/steptwo" method = "POST" id='myForm'>
         <p>ID <input type = "text" name = "id" /></p>
         <p>Name <input type = "text" name = "name" /></p>
         <p>Email <input type = "text" name = "email" /></p>
         <p>Website <input type ="text" name = "website" /></p>
         <p>



<table id="myTable" style="border: 1px solid black">
<th>requestPhoneNr</th><th>requestTopic</th><th>requestDescription</th><th>requestOriginator</th><th></th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="requestPhoneNr" class="requestPhoneNr" />
       </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="requestTopic" class="requestTopic" />
        </td>
                <td>
            <input type="text" name="requestDescription" class="requestDescription" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="requestOriginator" class="requestOriginator" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Insert row">
</p> 
<script>
$('#myTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
    $('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
     $('#myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="requestPhoneNr" class="requestPhoneNr" /></td><td><input type="text" name="requestTopic" class="requestTopic" /></td><td><input type="text" name="requestDescription" class="requestDescription" /></td><td><input type="text" name="requestOriginator" class="requestOriginator" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td></tr>')
});
</script>
</p>

     <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
  </form>
      <script>
$('#myForm').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var items = [];
    $('#myTable tr').each((i, el) => {
        var item = {};

        var inputs = $(el).find("input").each((i, inputEl) => {
            if (inputEl.type != "text") {
                return;
            }

            var name = $(inputEl).attr("name");
            var val = $(inputEl).val();
            item[name] = val;
        });

        items.push(item);
    });

    // remove empty object made from table header
    items = items.filter(i => Object.keys(i).length != 0);

      $.ajax({
        url: e.target.action,
        crossDomain: true,
        method: e.target.method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: items,
        headers: {
              "accept": "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
          }
        success: function () {
            // TODO: do success behaviors
        }
    });
});
    </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

@Raffy Alcoriza I'm trying to include your answer below into my form.html. However, now when I press on 'submit' button nothing happens. I checked in Web Inspector and received the following errors:

[image]

[image]

Would you be able to tell what am I doing wrong? (also, I'm assuming that there are no changes needed in myform.py) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to override your submit button to get all of your rows and compile them first into an array of items before you submit.

```
$('#myForm').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var items = [];
    $('#myTable tr').each((i, el) => {
        var item = {};

        var inputs = $(el).find("input").each((i, inputEl) => {
            if (inputEl.type != "text") {
                return;
            }

            var name = $(inputEl).attr("name");
            var val = $(inputEl).val();
            item[name] = val;
        });

        items.push(item);
    });

    // remove empty object made from table header
    items = items.filter(i => Object.keys(i).length != 0);

    $.ajax({
        url: e.target.action,
        method: e.target.method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: items,
        success: function () {
            // TODO: do success behaviors
        }
    });
});
```

Be sure to add the `name` attribute to your dynamically generated table rows, same as with previous:

```
$('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $('#myTable').append(`
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="requestPhoneNr" class="requestPhoneNr" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="requestTopic" class="requestTopic" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="requestDescription" class="requestDescription" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="requestOriginator" class="requestOriginator" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>`)
});
```

Finally, your Flask app should receive the data as a whole list of items via `response.data`.

Comment: Hi @Raffy Alcoriza, I've tried your answer but now my submit button doesn't do anything when I click on it. Would you be able to tell what am i doing wrong? I edited my question above. Thanks!

Comment: @Baobab1988 Have you checked DevTools if the Network tab has successfully pinged `/steptwo`?

Comment: added screenshot from DevTools above and tested with and without the code from your answer. These errors are thrown only when adding <script> $('#myForm').submit((e) => {... </script> to form.html. Without this  it will still only submit the first row added to myTable, but not multiple rows. Did I place it correctly in my file? Any ideas what can be wrong? thanks!

Comment: I tried editing $.ajax bit... I added headers and crossDomain attributes. So at the moment there are no errors shown in DevTool but only one row from myTable is being saved into CSV file instead of multiple rows if there are more than one added.

Comment: @Baobab1988 As mentioned, you need to update your Flask endpoint by using `response.data`, as it should return you the list of data that came from the form. Iterate over it accordingly while writing on your CSV file.